# Title label in Widget doesn’t show up

Tags: wordpress, widget, footer

I use Local as my localhost. I tried to create a widget using this function in PHP and add Custom HTML, but I cannot write the Title, because this label doesn't show up on the form and it doesn't display on my website either. I even tried writing a heading but it shows only plain text.

This is what I have in functions.php:

```
function custom_footer_widget_one() {
    $args = array(
        'id'            => 'footer-widget-col-one',
        'name'          => __('Footer Column One', 'text_domain'),
        'description'   => __('Column One', 'text_domain'),
        'before_title'  => '<h3 class="title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h3>',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>'
    );
    register_sidebar( $args );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'custom_footer_widget_one');
```

and this is what I have in footer.php:

```
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'footer-widget-col-three' ); ?>
```

And this is my Admin Widget: [image]

Comment: You're using two different IDs in your code: `'footer-widget-col-one'` in your `custom_footer_widget_one()` function, and `'footer-widget-col-three'` in footer.php. Is that a mistake?

Comment: You're right. I meant about this function function custom_footer_widget_three() {
 $args = array(
  'id'       => 'footer-widget-col-three',
  'name'      => __('Footer Column Three', 'text_domain'),
  'description'   => __('Column Three', 'text_domain'),
  'before_title'  => '<h3 class="title">',
  'after_title'   => '</h3>',
  'before_widget'  => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
  'after_widget'    => '</div>'
 );
 register_sidebar( $args );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'custom_footer_widget_three');

Comment: You can update your question.